# Does a PhD by monograph make you ineligible to be a lecturer at a university?

Tags: phd

I heard that a Ph.D. by publication is better than the one by a monograph.

Does that mean academic positions are available only for a researcher who has a Ph.D. by publication? In other words, if she/he has a PhD by monograph then she/he cannot be a lecturer at a uni, where a lecturer need to have some publications,

Comment: This certainly isn't a general worldwide rule.  It's possible that some institutions in some countries have such a rule, but you'd have to look at them specifically.

Comment: Even for my monograph I needed to have several papers. So these two approaches are not mutually exclusive...

Comment: Several fields in some countries (e.g. history in Germany) would make the exact opposite claim: If you haven't written a "real" book (meaning a book weighting less than two kilos) you are not a serious academic. (I am only slightly exaggerating) So the answer really depends on the discipline and the country.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never heard on a difference between the degree. If you've finished a Ph.D. in some subject, you have finished a Ph.D. on the subject. You've done the research necessary and was approved by your committee and the university's senate (or whoever approves it there).

Whether or not you get a job depends on the quality of the content of your dissertation, your reference letters, networking skills, and just plain luck with timing.

Even if we agree that Ph.D. based on publications is better, then the only difference is that it might give you a slight edge with regards to the content of your dissertation. But ultimately, it's about what's inside rather than what form it ended up in.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

No. Even if we accept your premise (which sounds dubious to me), there is no reason to assume that academic positions are only for those P.h.D.s.

Of course, it could be that a certain person who is hiring has a certain bias. You probably cannot do much about this anyway (and, very sadly, gender bias seems to be much more common..)

I don't understand your title, by the way.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I just headed that if I awarded a PhD by monograph then I cannot be a lecturer.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've often heard people say that a monograph thesis shows more that you know well a your field than a research paper thesis does. (Of course, you should still publish papers!)

Comment: One downvoted seems to disagree with me, however -- could you state your opinion?

Comment: +1 I agree with you that instead of downvoted, people should express their idea.